# Reseting a const variable, even though it's const (ES6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Understanding variable scopes

```js
const { response } = somecall();
if (response) {
   const { response } = someOtherCallThatReturnsUndefined(response);
   // the value of response being passed in to **someOtherCallThatReturnsUndefined** is actually undefined
}
```

Comment: no, you are declaring two differents objects with the a variable of the same name inside

Comment: They're two different variables. ([Example](https://jsfiddle.net/erd0znc9/1/))

Comment: okay this all makes sense, I'm going to go ahead and delete this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is called [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

When you declare a variable with `const` (or `let`) it's block-scoped: the second time you're declaring a new `response` constant you're in a different scope, so they're different variables. But the fact that they shares the same name, means you're *shadowing* the outer one (that could potentially lead to bugs); and preventing the inner scope to access to the variable of the outer scope.

To be clear:

```
  const foo = "1";
  {
     const foo = "bar";
     console.log(foo); // "bar"
  }
  console.log(foo); // "1";
```

The variable `foo` in the inner block is a totally different variable than the `foo` in the outer block, in fact when you exit the block you still have the right value. They just "shares" the same name, that's it.

Comment: This really cleared things up, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By saying `const { response }` you are declaring the variable in a different context than the original variable hence why you can do so.